# How to Use Group By for Single Column in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query written for `MySql` that uses the LIMIT and GROUP BY keywords. It works on fine on MySql. The query is:

```
SELECT 
     tester,
     firstname, 
     COUNT(*) total 
FROM mnrelease_details a LEFT JOIN users b ON tester='guest'  
WHERE a.project='testpro'  
GROUP BY tester ORDER BY total ASC LIMIT 10;
```

I tried to translated it to T-Sql for use on Sql Server. Here is what I have for `Sql Server`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
      tester,
      firstname, 
      COUNT(*) total 
FROM mnrelease_details a 
LEFT JOIN users b ON tester='guest'  
WHERE a.project='testpro' 
GROUP BY tester ORDER BY total ASC;
```

However, when I try to use that on Sql Server, I get this error:

> Column 'users.firstname' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why doesn't Sql Server allow this? Why won't Sql Server allow the single GROUP BY instead of adding all the columns in `GROUP BY`? I want to group by the `tester` column only, like I did with MySql.

Answer (score 2):

What if you had data like this?

```
tester   firstname
------   ---------
  1      Joe
  2      Bob
  2      Fred
```

Which firstname do you expect to show up for tester 2: Bob, or Fred? If you need both, then add the column to the group by yourself, because the firstname column is part of your defined group. If you don't care, then just pick an aggregate function like `MIN()` or `MAX()`: it doesn't matter. If you do care, then you need to build something into the query to tell it how to select the value from the right record.

The point is that the original query is potentially ambiguous. Perhaps you have data such that it's never a problem, but the query engine doesn't know that up front. MySql's behavior here is actually the wrong behavior, and a departure from the ansi sql standard (at least, for sql-92 and prior).

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, SQL Server is strict on non-aggregated fields being on the GROUP BY clause, so it doesn't allow this, you need to add the `firstname` field to the `GROUP BY` clause after `tester` assuming tester being unique and each having the same `firstname`.

You can check [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for more information about this issue.